# infinite summation with finite summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I am stuck in this;
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{e^{-3ln(n)}}{\sqrt{12\pi ln(n)}} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{e^{-3ln(n)}}{\sqrt{12\pi ln(n)}}$$

Is this equality true?
Both are lower than infinite?

Comment: The LHS seems to have something wrong with it, and the equation is false as written...

Comment: The RHS should be $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{ne^{-3ln(n)}}{\sqrt{12\pi ln(n)}}$

Comment: you have lost a factor "n"

Comment: For convergence, note that $e^{-3\ln n}=\frac 1{n^3}$...

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \ln x gives $\ln x$ compared with ln x which gives $ln x$

Comment: Thanks guys, I missed n, because of this it seemed wrong to me. Thanks for your interest:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing on the left depends on $k$, so all terms in the inner sum are equal and the whole sum is just $n$ times the term.  Then $e^{-3\ln(n)}=(e^{\ln(n)})^{-3}=n^{-3}$ so your sum becomes
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{e^{-3\ln(n)}}{\sqrt{12\pi \ln(n)}} =\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{n\cdot n^{-3}}{\sqrt{12\pi \ln(n)}} =\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{n^{-2}}{\sqrt{12\pi \ln(n)}}$$
which is nicely convergent because of the $n^{-2}$ factor.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%5E(-2)%2Fsqrt(12*pi*log(n))%20from%202%20to%20infinity) tells us it is about $0.0982675$

Comment: Thanks :) I just missed "n" :)